# Reporting robust regressions?

Tags: regression, robust, reporting

I'm running robust regressions in R (rlm from the MASS package) for 3 different models of regressions that are all related:
DV ~ IV1 + error
DV ~ IV1 + IV2 + error
DV ~ IV2 + error
I was wondering what I should be reporting in a table/my results section. As of now I have the beta coefficients, standard errors, and p-values in a table.I was hoping someone could clarify if there are any other important measures that I should include.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What is typical in your field to report?

Comment: Agreed with @Dave, probably best to adhere to what is customarily reported in your field. I’d also just add that the sample size for each model might be a useful parameter to include.